# BufferedReader is sometimes empty

Tags: resources, bufferedreader

I have Loader class where I load txt file into BufferedReader from resources and return this field. I use this method but it acts really strange(for me). When I don't put 
`String str = bufferReader.readLine();` after 
`bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);` 
(in Loader class) than bufferReader in another class is empty, and readLine() returns null. When I write that piece of code in Loader class, I can read each line from txt, except the 1. one which is read in Loader class. Also, I can't read last line if I dont put enter at the end.

```
public BufferedReader loadFromFileToBufferReader(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        System.out.print(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/" + fileName));
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("resources/" + fileName).getFile());
        BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file)) {
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String str = bufferReader.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Something went terribly wrong with file reading");
        }
        return bufferReader;
    }
```

and usage:

```
public Database() {
        productsInDatabse = new ArrayList<>();
        codesList = new ArrayList<>();
        loader = new LoadFromFile();
        BufferedReader output = loader.loadFromFileToBufferReader("database.txt");
        Product product;
        String line;
        String[] array;
        try {

            line = output.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should paste your code here because it's hard to deduce all the possible causes of this without seeing the code on 100% but I am guessing you have it the same file open at the same time from multiple sources without closing it before from one? Could be literally millions of little things, just telling you how the same error happened to me.

Comment: Yes, much better :) I'd try inizializing the bufferedReader in database with a file from the loadingclass  and see if it works, You change the return type to File and getTheFile with a specified path see if it works like you load a file into a file variable thought the class and put the file into the buffered reader  in the database ... if it works after you are 100% sure the problem is in the loadFromFileClass

Comment: I'd think if I can use String instead of BufferedReader, it will solve this problem I think, but I have to figure out how can I work with String instead of BufferedReader

Comment: public File loadFromFileToBufferReader(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
   System.out.print(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/" + fileName));
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("resources/" + fileName).getFile());
        return file;
    } public Database() {
       try{ BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(loader.loadFromFileToBufferReader("database.txt"));}catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("message");} This way u use the loader for leading the File and initiate the BR in the database using that